# DC.js exclude part of data from a chart

Tags: dc.js, crossfilter

I am a real newbie to d3 and js. I am trying to present the total of our "live" orders on a pie chart.

The csv I am using includes all orders, completed too, and I would like to exclude the completed orders from the pie. I do not want to delete them from the csv because the file is the data source for other graphs that will need those values later on.

I tried to use a filter in the dc.chart section like this

```
 ".filter([["Backlog","BAU","BAU Parked","Project Parked"]])"
```

but this way the Completed orders do appear greyed out.

Is there a way to exclude them altogether?

Comment: You don’t say whether the pie chart is displaying the same dimension as the status values you want to exclude. If so, you can use a [fake group](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/wiki/FAQ#fake-groups), specifically [this one](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/wiki/FAQ#remove-particular-bins), to adapt the group. If not, it’s a little trickier but also possible.